# cannot view document in ravendb studio

Tags: ravendb

When I try to view my document I get this error:

```
Client side exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Document's property: "DocumentData" is too long to view in the studio (property length: 699.608, max allowed length: 500.000)
at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.AssertNoPropertyBeyondSize(RavenJToken token, Int32 maxSize, String path)
at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.AssertNoPropertyBeyondSize(RavenJToken token, Int32 maxSize, String path)
at Raven.Studio.Models.EditableDocumentModel.<LoadModelParameters>b__2a(DocumentAndNavigationInfo result)
at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17`1.<>c__DisplayClass19.<ContinueOnSuccessInTheUIThread>b__16()
at AsyncCompatLibExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass55.<InvokeAsync>b__54()
```

I am saving a pdf in that field.
I want to be able to edit the other fields.
Is it possible for it to ignore the field that's too big?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't save large binary (or base64 encoded) data into the json document.  That's a poor use of the database.  Instead, you should consider one of these two options:

### Option 1

- Write the binary data to disk (or cloud storage) yourself.
- Save a file path (or url) to it in your document.

### Option 2

- Use Raven's [attachments](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/attachments) feature.  This is a separate area in the database meant specifically for storing binary files.
- The advantage is that your binary documents are included in database backups, and if you like you can take advantage of features like my [Indexed Attachments Bundle](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-IndexedAttachments), or write your own custom bundles that use attachment [triggers](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/extending/plugins).
- The disadvantage is that your database can grow very large.  For this reason, many prefer option 1.